# matplotlib heatmap - plot odd indices

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, heatmap

I want to create a heatmap plotting the classification accuracy of a convolutional neural network with varying kernel sizes. In my particular implementation of a CNN I use only odd size filters, but the heatmap being plotted is placing the plot elements at both odd and even positions. Whats the correct way to ignore the even positions, and to plot the elements at only the odd positions?

I start by defining the kernel widths and heights that I'm interested in:

```
search_height = range(1, 5, 2)  # [1,3]
search_width = range(1, 5, 2)  # [1,3]
```

Preallocate an array to hold the accuracy values. I think this might be part of the problem as its storing values in even indices?

```
grid_accuracy = np.empty((len(search_height), len(search_width)))  # 2x2 array
```

I then get the accuracy of the network for different kernel sizes and store them in the array:

```
for i, h in enumerate(search_height):
    for j, w in enumerate(search_width):
        cur_test_acc = main(batch_size=200, num_epochs=100, k_height=h, k_width=w)
        grid_accuracy[i, j] = cur_test_acc
```

Finally I plot a heatmap with the stored accuracy values:

```
plt.imshow(grid_accuracy, cmap = plt.cm.hot, interpolation='none')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Kernel Width')
plt.ylabel('Kernel Height')
plt.xticks(search_width)
plt.yticks(search_height)
```

The problem is that I end up with a plot that looks like this:

[image]

Currently it seems to be using the horizontal and vertical index of `grid_accuracy` as the location of the elements.

What I actually want is just a 2x2 grid, where the value of each cell is the accuracy for the respective kernel width/height. The axis ticks should be the  heights and widths that I manually defined (ideally with the horizontal axis ticks above the plot):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the tick *labels* rather than just their positions:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(np.random.randn(2, 2), interpolation='none')
plt.xticks([0, 1], [1, 3])
plt.yticks([0, 1], [1, 3])
```

You can use `plt.tick_params` to get the format you're looking for:

```
plt.tick_params(length=0, labelbottom=False, labeltop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. In reality I have many more filter sizes of interest rather than just `[1,3]`. Is there a way to automatic the setting of the labels so I don't need to manually type it all out?

Comment: Also, how would I move the x title to above the plot as well?

Comment: You can pass `range(1, 5, 2)` as the label parameter to `plt.ticks` (and the tick locations are just `range(grid.shape[1])` and `range(grid.shape[0])` for the x and y axes respectively). I already showed how to move the x tick labels to the top using `tick_params`.

Comment: When I say the x title, I mean the title of the horizontal axis ('Kernel Width'). The formatting you provided only moves the tick labels, but  not the x axis title

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out by using a subplot and `ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')`